# First leftBarButtonItem is hiding

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I used 2 bar button items. One is for back button and second is for the title. It is working fine. But when the title string is large, the title shifts to left and back button does not appear, but it is working.

I am also using a rightBarButtonItem, that is attached with a badge button. But that is not affecting this as I have tried the same code after removing that button. This is my code -

```
let backBtnImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Back Image")!
let Back: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backBtnImg, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonAction))

let titleStr = ("titleString")
let titleItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: titleStr, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [Back, titleItem]
```

I have attached both the images.

[image: When title is small]

[image: When title is large]

Comment: Why you are not using self.title?

Comment: it means 565 hide the back arrow, am I right?

Comment: @SaurabhJain look at the second image. Long titles were hiding back arrow.

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi because I didn't want that in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code if you want to set the title in left side. It may helps to you.

In `viewDidLoad` method

```
let navView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)! - 50, height: 40))
    lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navView.frame.size.width - 40, height: 40))
    lblTitle?.text = strTitle
    lblTitle?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    lblTitle?.textColor = UIColor.white
    lblTitle?.textAlignment = .left
    navView.addSubview(lblTitle!)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navView
```

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations. So, my vote is not getting counted. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use this One It help you

-> take only one left button

-> For Title use: `self.navigationItem.title = "Navigation Title"`

```
 let backBtnImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back")!
        let Back: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backBtnImg, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonAction))
        self.navigationItem.title = "Navigation Title"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [Back]
```

Comment: I don't want title. I want title in left corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupNevigationBar(){
            let btnBack = UIButton(type: .custom)
            btnBack.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "back"), for: .normal)
            btnBack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBackPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            let itemBack = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)

            let titleStr = ("Regular Title")
            let titleItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: titleStr, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [itemBack, titleItem]

            self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(itemBack, animated: true)
        }
```

[image]

[image]